# Html page parsing using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, regex, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm, trying to parse [the IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000013/reviews?count=3188) with Regex (I know HAP is better), but my RegEx is wrong, so may be you can advice me how to use HAP correctly.

This is the part of page I'm trying to parse. I need to take 2 numbers from here:

### 5 out of 5 people (so these two five's i need, two numbers)

```
<small>5 out of 5 people found the following review useful:</small>
<br>
<a href="/user/ur1174211/">
<h2>Interesting, Particularly in Comparison With "La Sortie des usines Lumière"</h2>
<b>Author:</b>
<a href="/user/ur1174211/">Snow Leopard</a>
<small>from Ohio</small>
<br>
<small>10 March 2005</small>
```

and this is my code on c#

```
Regex reg1 = new Regex("([0-9]+(out of)+[0-9])");
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the heading of the movie is {0}", header[i].InnerHtml);
            Match m = reg1.Match(header[i].InnerHtml);

            if (!m.Success)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string str1 = m.Value.Split(' ')[0];
                string str2 = m.Value.Split(' ')[3];

                if (!Int32.TryParse(str1, out index1))
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (!Int32.TryParse(str2, out index2))
                {
                    return;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("index1 = {0}", index1);
                Console.WriteLine("index2 = {0}", index2);
            }
        }
```

Big thanks to everybody who read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. This way you will take numbers not only digits.

```
    Regex reg1 = new Regex(@"(\d* (out of) \d*)");
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("the heading of the movie is {0}", header[i].InnerHtml);
      Match m = reg1.Match(header[i].InnerHtml);

      if (!m.Success)
      {
          return;
      }
      else
      {
          Regex reg2 = new Regex(@"\d+");
          m = reg2.Match(m.Value);
          string str1 = m.Value;
          string str2 = m.NextMatch().Value;

          if (!Int32.TryParse(str1, out index1))
          {
              return;
          }
          if (!Int32.TryParse(str2, out index2))
          {
              return;
          }
          Console.WriteLine("index1 = {0}", index1);
          Console.WriteLine("index2 = {0}", index2);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the InnerHtml of the `small` tag then this can also be done to get numbers

```
var title = "5 out of 5 people found the following review useful:";
var titleNumbers = title.ToCharArray().Where(x => Char.IsNumber(x));
```

**EDIT**

as @PulseLab suggests, i have an alternate method

```
var sd = s.Split(' ').Where((data) =>
        {
            var datum = 0;
            int.TryParse(data, out datum);
            return datum > 0;
        }).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work if the numbers in iMDB were in double digits, e.g. "10 out of 12 people found the following review useful" - would you not end up with an array of 4 numeric chars in that case?

Comment: Numbers can be big like "112 out of 504" etc, this is the usefulness of the review to the movie

Comment: @Kate21 you call that "112 out of 504" big